# Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting

Tags: hardware, boot-issues

I got a raspberry pi 3 b+ for Christmas and yesterday whilst installing a Pi Hat's Software (Rasp.io Duino) it just flat out died after showing that there was an under-voltage, even though I was using a 5.2V 9W 1.8A Amazon Alexa Power Adaptor(I am now using an IPAD 10W 5.1V 2.1A Power Adapter) , It was using BerryBoot with Raspbian and Retropie and it now uses NOOBS but it just shows the PWR LED and no ACT light activity, I've read this means that it can't read anything off the sd card but this sd card works perfectly as I had to put NOOBS onto it. This also happened with a raspberry pi 2 that I had
BTW There also is 3v Power Output coming off the GPIO so it can't be this:[Raspberry Pi Forum Post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)

I have tried to flash the sd card with the latest image of raspbian and Etcher and it still shows the same symptoms

After a while, the chips get warmer but not enough the chips actually doing anything

It **does not boot** anymore and I don't see any rainbow screen **at all**

Sorry if I'm a bit short, I'm just stressed with this situation

Edit: Now with a new rpi 3b+ the same thing has happened, but I have some extra info, the pi's 5v power is working but there seems to be no 3v3 coming in on the gpio, once again the red light is on but no green light and the I found it happened after shorting the 5v and ground pins by accident

I have just realised that i have contradicted myself :-/

Comment: power supply recommended for the 3B+ is 2.5A - so you're very short :p however, 1.8A should be enough with nothing connected

Comment: `now uses NOOBS` - did you flash a NOOBS image onto an SD card? if so, how? - `This also happened with a raspberry pi 2 that I had BTW` did you fix that?

Comment: *"this sd card works perfectly as I had to put NOOBS onto it."* -> That doesn't mean the card is formatted correctly. It should have an MBR and the first partition should be vfat.

Comment: Try booting only the Pi, screen, and keyboard (i.e. without a HAT or anything else connected to the expansion header).  Does that work?

Comment: @JaromandaX I was using the NOOBS zip file

Comment: how were you using it

Comment: @JaromandaX Copying and pasting, but I have put in the question now that it shows the same symptoms after flashing the .img of raspbian using the latest version of etcher

Comment: so, you copied noobs zip file onto an SD card - that's not how you do it

Comment: @JaromandaX **read the rest of it ** also i extracted it on there

Comment: Sorry. I didn't really read all of it

Comment: Hi *Bob*, Welcome :-) Don't be stressed. Here are really many of us who try to help you. But in this situation it is the best to examine that your hardware is working as expected. You should follow the suggestion *Joan* has made in his comment. Download [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian) and do [Installing operating system images](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md).

Comment: Please don't use NOOBS, flash the image direct to the SD Card. This definitely works. Many others have done it successful. If it does not work then we cannot do much to help you. Then it is very likely that you have a problem with your hardware or your environment. Maybe use another RasPi or SD Card or power supply or something else.

Comment: The card may have been underpowered while writing causing subtle errors.  Can you try with a new card with your new and larger power supply?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am using an in built laptop sd card writer that has worked many times before

Comment: The pi also writes to the card while using it - at _that_ time.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am now using a power adapter that is 5.1V and 2.1A so I don't think that is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, the raspberry pi is dead

Sorry for keeping this question open for so long, I forgot about it ages ago and only just saw it again

Answer (score 5):

Read it again: [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) it covers 99.999% of reasons your RPi won't boot.

Then download plain Raspbian and https://etcher.io and use Etcher to rewrite your SDCard. It's highly likely that the version of Raspbian on the card is too old for your RPi3B+ hardware.

The common symptom of Raspbian that's too old is the lightning arrow for undervoltage. It's a massive clue.

Comment: I am using the latest version of raspbian

Comment: No you are not. Use NOOBS 3.0.0 or plain Raspbian 2018-11-13 or PINN v3.0.1 (see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=142574&start=650) as the lightning bolt means the firmware doesn't recognise your RPi board.

Comment: It isn't booting up, i can't see any lightning bolt anymore

Comment: BTW I can see where your getting this from and it does not apply to me [link] (https://support.thepihut.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000553589-My-Raspberry-Pi-3B-won-t-boot-)

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me with NOOBS, I just downloaded the Raspbian .zip from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ and flashed it using Balena Etcher from https://etcher.io/ Its really simple to use and you don't even need to unzip the file. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you had read my question you would have seen that I had done this BTW thx for being polite

Comment: Tried your methodology (using .zip instead of extracting .img) but it did not work