# Raspberry Pi 3 won't boot, red LED light only

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, led

I was using my RPi for testing the sensors of my project, when suddenly it stopped and won't boot after that. I did not touch anything nor destroyed parts of the pi. The sd card is working fine as it boots up on my 2nd pi, nothing has changed on my files and none got corrupted. I've tried plugging it to hdmi to see if there would be an output but none so far. What happened to my pi? :(

Comment: you connected the last sensor you were testing badly and destroyed parts of the pi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting)

Comment: How do you know for sure you didn't break your Pi? Especially if you were connecting external sensors to it.