# Raspberry Pi Zero W not booting(ACT green led weak blink)

Tags: act

Raspberry Pi Zero W ACT green led weak blink and not booting. But sd card is working in Raspberry pi 3. Stretch and Jessie installed but both did not work
What is the problem? SD card Samsung
Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lf2acvYb9dA&t=11s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting)

Comment: Raspbery Pi 3 Original Element14

Comment: What do you mean in your comment? Please look at [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)

Comment: sorry i misunderstood you