# Pi not booting, no green light(multiple reboots)

Tags: raspbian, boot, boot-issues

My Pi isn't booting, it was working just a day ago and i didn't change anything, the only thing i did multiple times is cut the supply power to reboot it to see why is my LCD screen is not working while i was trying to fix it.
Now is not booting, no green light and no signal found on the spare monitor i use it on.
The SD card is the same, nothing changed. I tried leaving it on for some time but nothing happened.

Comment: It is possible the SD card became corrupt when you cut power to it. You may need to re-image the card and see if that helps. Or try a new card with a fresh image to see if thats the problem.

Comment: So I lost all the data?

Comment: If you didnt have your code/data backed up AND this is what happened then yes, probably lost it all. But I would confirm that this is the problem by using a new card with fresh image. You can also try mounting the existing card in another machine and see if you can get your data off of it.

Comment: couple side notes....   Should always try and shutdown the pi correctly before yanking power from it.  And you should use git or other methods to back up code/data.

Comment: Noted, I will be more careful this time

Comment: Was that the issue?

Comment: I don't know yet, I am not home so I can't access the sd card

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting), meaning this answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92675/79866

Comment: Hey Chad, I format the sd and install NOOBS on it but still doesn't boot, any more suggestions?

Comment: @ChadG it's still doesn't boot man

Comment: Happen to have a second pi you can try the card on to ensure it's good?  Not sure man

Comment: @ChadG Unfortunately no