# Raspberry Not Powering Up

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, boot-issues

Hope you are all doing fine !! Actually I'm just a beginner with raspberry Pi ... I started doing python coding on it a few days ago. But now when I'm connecting my charger to it ,It won't start. Neither that red LED of power Blinks(means it is off not turning on) Help related to this would be appreciated.Thanks in advanced

Comment: `Neither that red LED of power Blinks.` what exactly do you mean by that? It should be on at all times. Does it stay off, blink or stay off at all times?

Comment: If it does not power up and the red LED is off, you probably burned it up.  A low-quality power supply could do that even if you had nothing else connected. If you had something connected, then it could have a short even with a good power supply.  Regardless, there's not enough information here to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting). Please read [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151). And please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: try a different power supply, and, if the cable is removable from the power supply, a different cable

Answer (score 2):

You can try a couple of things.

1. Can try a different power adapter.
2. It could be a hardware failure as well. So contact your vendor and ask for the replacement.
3. Make a video. Upload on YouTube and show us the problem via the link. This could help us to diagnose the problem in detail.