# only PWR led is on but ACT led is not

Tags: pi-3a+

I got a Raspberry Pi 3 Model A+. I immediately inserted an sd card and booted it up it went well for one day and then after an update, I could not reboot it up so then I formatted the sd card and installed noobs in it again. but this time some of the apps didn't start like sonic pi, sense hat emulator and chromium. After much trying I finally thought of reinstalling the os and This time I thought of dual booting it with Raspbian and LibreELEC_RPi2. So now both the os didn't work. I thought this could be an issue with the power supply because in the instructions it was written 5V and 2.5A(min), and I was using a charger of 2.4A. After that, I checked the rating of the original RPI power supply, which was 3A, so I got a charger of the same rating.

After I plugged it in the socket there was some fluctuation in the main power supply and now only PWR led lights up and not ACT led. I tried formatting the card again, even bought a new sd card reader, I even tried booting with a pen drive.

Please tell me what to do as I am a beginner in this.

Comment: `then after an update` what update? `dual booting it with Raspbian and LibreELEC_RPi2` how? best thing to do is to do a very basic install first before trying "dual boot" or anything at all advanced, check it works - if that doesn't work, try a different sd card

Comment: the update that occurs after booting Raspbian for the first time, I skipped that the time so I had to do that from the terminal. I dual booted using noobs. I did it in case I can not open Raspbian so I would still have the other one to use.

Comment: `the update that occurs after booting Raspbian for the first time` - oh, where it expands the root filesystem? and that breaks the install? seems like noobs is broken

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting). Please look at the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92675/79866)