# Raspberry Pi not booting, even when I install NOOBS on a formatted usb

Tags: hardware, boot-issues

I have this problem for a while now, the rpi doesn't boot.

The red led is on but the green led never opens. I have formatted the SD card and re-install NOOBS on it but again I can't boot it. Before this problem appeared I opened and close the power supply because I wanted to fix the LCD that I have. I think I messed up the SD card reader. I tried most of the things I found on the internet nothing made it boot.

Will I need a new Raspberry Pi? 
If anyone has any suggestions I am happy to hear them.

Comment: which model pi is it

Comment: @JaromandaX rpi 3 b+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting). Please look at [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Comment: @Ingo I have already checked that, nothing works

Comment: PI3B+, good, because that can boot from USB out-of-the-box Try imaging a USB drive and see if that boots - at least then you can narrow down the issue

Comment: if I use the SD card on a usb converter will it work?

Comment: sure - that can work too - of course, if that doesn't work, that doesn't rule out the sd card as somehow being at fault - though unlikely that you can write to it in one PC and not read it in pi, but stranger things have happened - I'm also assuming pi3b+ can boot from USB out of the box (according to something I read over at rpi org)

Comment: @JaromandaX it doesn't work either, I will try another usb and see if it works

Comment: Are you able to measure 3.3V between pin#1 & pin#6 (or pin#9). Have you been abusing the gpio pins in any way? A short circuit between pin#2 or pin#4 and any other pin lets the magic blue smoke escape and your RPI can only be fixed for £35 (aka a new one).

Comment: @Dougie yes I have messed with the GPIOs, damn it

Comment: You wrote that you have checked [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151), but nothing works. What failed first?

Comment: @Ingo First I install the latest NOOBS version and I format the SD card, then I cover the 3v3 gpio port, even tried heating it up with a blow dryer. Nothing worked

Comment: You do not follow The Boot Problems Sticky so you cannot say "Nothing worked." There are instructions if NOOBS does not work. Have you ever read it?

Comment: Do you mean to burn the OS? Because I did that too

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it again, follow the guidelines below:

1. Download official OS from [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)
2. Format your microSD card via [CD card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/).
3. Flash your `.img` file to microSD via [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) which is recommended by Raspberry.
4. boot it to your Raspberry Pi 3b+ or other Raspberry Pi.
5. Be happy :)

if you have any questions, you can find [the full description here](https://github.com/romankh3/raspberrypi-home-ecosystem/blob/master/BASE_CONFIGURATION.md).

Comment: Already tried that, didn't help

Comment: Have you tried to do it with another SD card?

Comment: no but this sd works on my pc and mobile

Comment: Looks like your issue related to raspberry hardware. Do you search how to check raspberry? Something like `health check`. It can help you to understand that hardware ok or not.

Comment: I will do one when I get home

Comment: Please, write about it after. It can be very useful for others, including me :)

Comment: will I have to boot it first?