# My Pi 3 B suddenly stopped

Tags: pi-3

My Pi 3 B+ suddenly stopped working. I formatted the SD card and put NOOBS 3.1 but it still won't boot. The red power LED is on but the yellow ACT LED does blink for sometime but I don't get any display through the HDMI port.

I used a 2.5A but no effect. Is it a possible cause of this kind of issue? I had used this Pi a couple of times before with the same power supply and apparently it was working fine. I also checked 3v3 pin, it's working fine. I also checked with latest raspbain os and also with older version but

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting). Also read the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Comment: what is a 2.5A and how did you use it?

Comment: `the yellow ACT LED does blink for sometime` count the flashes, the number of flashes indicate where in the bootstrap process the pi is failing