# Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 3 b+ doesn't boot

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, boot-issues, raspbian-buster

All was working fine till I left my Pi 3 b+ board turned on for around **4-5 days** along side windows on my monitor.

Now, when I connect power to it, only red **power led glows constant red**. **Yellow led doesn't glow** and the board refuse to boot. I freshly installed Raspbian **Buster** but it didn't change anything.

Then I used a usb drive for booting just in case my memory card is corrupted(*installed Raspbian buster on usb drive*), but still nothing good(*I didn't change OTP as I am using Pi 3 b+ here*). So, clearly corrupted memory card is not the problem here.

I then used my multimeter to check continuity and voltage, to check if led was broken or USBs don't work, but still **everything is continuous and all USBs are working fine**. Power supply is legit too.

I don't think that the board is defective as I didn't tweaked anything and even multimeter shows some areas(where I tested) are working fine.

***Can anyone suggest the solution to this or any troubleshooting options?***

**UPDATE**
*I will keep my PI in freezer for some days just to try it for a last time. I will get back to the solution then(if any).*

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think "buster" can boot from USB - I know it won't on pi4 (yet) - have you tried a different SDcard instead? or perhaps **stretch** on the USB

Comment: I tried stretch on USB but still it doesn't work. I am going to use another SDcard just to check if card is corrupted or not. I will come back later after that.

Comment: power supply is legit. I used another one just to be sure and still no good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting). Also read the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Comment: @Ingo Thanks for that read. Everything is concise and on point. Never could have asked for better troubleshooting solution. After reading that, I think I shorted 3V3 with 5V as 3V3 doesn't has any rise potential than GND(after testing through multimeter). I will keep my PI in freezer for some days anyway just to be sure it isn't some other issue.

Comment: If you have found the reason or a solution, so please make an answer to finish the question and show others that is has a solution.

Comment: "I think I shorted 3V3 with 5V" - This is more relevant for diagnosing a non-working board than the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update:**

I tried cooling my Pi but the same thing appears - **only red block glowing pwr led**. So, I bought a **new Pi 3 b+** and it is working **ok**.

Power supply was not the issue. As I commented earlier, *I might have shorted the 5V and 3V3 that seems to be the issue*.

Anyways I would be closing this question as solved.