# I can't tur on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card

I just bought my first R PI B+. I have a Kingston 128GB micro SD card with NOOBS downloaded on it. The device is connected to monitor with HDMI cable (I tried 3 different monitors), but it isn't booting.
Only the red light lighting, but the green ACT led doesn't even blinking.
My SD card works perfectly in my computer or even in my phone.

Can somebody help me? What can be the problem?

Comment: You need to say exactly HOW you setup the card. I might add that most of us **don't** use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697)
because of its limitations - it is easier to install Raspbian.

Comment: I formatted the SD card, than I unzipped the downloaded files to it.

Comment: "I formatted the SD card" - which file system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting). Also look at [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).