# raspberry pi 4 doesn't boot

Tags: gpio, power, boot-issues, pi-4

I have a raspberry pi 4 which was working and suddenly turned off and ever since isn't booting up.
Red and Greeen LED is continously on.(Not blinking)
I have tried another memory card with differnt OS it doesn't work.
Tried old memory card flashing again doesn't work either.
GPIO pin gets power though as i have tested it with an LED by hooking it up in 5v and 3v PIN.
Processor I guess is not doing anything as it is not warming up.
Are there any other troubleshooting i can do or is the pi gone for good?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting). Look at the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Comment: In the boot problems sticky linked to by both comments, just go all the way to the last (4th?) post - it's Pi4 specific

Comment: See [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

Comment: If have tried everything except trying USB A to USB A adapter.
Nothing works so far.
If it doesn't work what i can do with the broken PI ?
And what could have i done wrong, So that i'll be careful with my next purchase