# RPI not booting, only red LED, not the SD card

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, boot-issues

My RPI 3B+ won't boot up anymore. Only the red LED lights up, the green one remains off. I use the official power supply, and my SD card is not corrupted.

My SD card realy isn't the problem: I tried 3 different cards, each with a clean install of Raspbian Buster Lite.

Does anyone know what could be wrong, and especially how to fix it?

(It really isn't the SD card)

Comment: Sorry about mentioning this so often, but it really isn't the SD card. I've spent the past 2 hours googling the issue, and very fustratingly, that is the one and only answer that will ever show.

Comment: As a cross test, you could check how it behaves if you switch it on without an SD card in the slot. Even if the card is ok, this looks a bit like it wasn't recognized for whatever reason.

Comment: Without an SD card, what behaviour would be good and what would indicate a broken board?

Comment: Good question. I don't know, and I can't tell without testing (which I currently can't do, as my Pi is at home). But I guess if it behaves any different (i.e. the green light goes on), that would mean that it did previously detect the card.

Comment: what adapter you are using?

Comment: How are you 'installing Raspbian Buster Lite'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting). Please look also at the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Answer (score 1):

I think the board is hardbricked, and needs to be replaced. Nothing I tried made it work. I do find it weird that the system still has power, including the GPIO, on which I've connected a small cooling fan. The fan still spins when connected, but the RPI doesn't even get to the point where it reads the ssh file on the boot partition.